# How to Dropdown navmenu on hover

Tags: magento2, css, menu, navigation

I just add a new line of html code to navbar... now the navbar is not open on hover, i do have to click on the nav and to close, i have to click it agan.

But what i want , is that the nav open it by hover mouse.

here is the html tag:

```
<div class="menu-trigger-inner">

<span class="trigger-icon"><span class="line"></span><span class="line"></span><span class="line"></span></span>
<span class="label">ASSORTIMENTO</span>
</div>
```

The new piece of html code is this one:

```
<span class="label">ASSORTIMENTO</span>
```

[image]